# How do I get price value with currency, also size and color attribute value instead of id?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, json

```
public function productDataToJson(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
  $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
  $tree = $category->getTreeModel();
  $tree->load();
  $ids = $tree->getCollection()->getAllIds();
  $jsonFilePath = Mage::getBaseDir().'/jsondata';
  foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $array = array();
    $products = $category->load($id)
        ->getProductCollection()
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
         ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
    foreach ($products as $_product) {
        $array[] = array_merge($_product->getData(), array('category_ids' => $_product->getCategoryIds()));
    }
    $jsonData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($array);
    file_put_contents($jsonFilePath.'/c_' . $id . '_node.json', $jsonData);
  }
}
```

I am getting all this data in json file, but need price with currency, and size, color with its value lable eg. black, red. Now I am getting only ids of this 2 atttributes

Comment: $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($finalPrice, true, false);

Comment: Thanks @NAGARAJU KASA, Where to put this?

Comment: @NAGARAJU KASA, its not working :(

Comment: let me know exact event name u r using

Comment: May I know what is the exact requirement or task so that i will help u thanks

Comment: @NAGARAJU KASA,I want to save all product details (size,color,price)in json file after save,update product.So this will genrate json file with data, and I will fetch this data in frontend listing page.
I want price with the currency and color and size with its atribute label. 
Now I am getting only ids of this two attributes and remaining data is ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62344/discussion-between-sushant-thorat-and-nagaraju-kasa).